# Moving to second form

Tags: database-design, database-normalization

Guys, how would you create second form of this table (primary key is: {isbn,copy}):
**isbn** AB-1234-X
         **authorID**   IC45
    **authorName**   I.Conn
 **title** The ﬁnal curtain
      **copy** 2
     **classiﬁcation** Detectiveﬁction
      **userID**      xyz44

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A relation is in 2NF iff

- it's in 1NF, and
- every non-prime attribute is
  dependent on the whole of every
  candidate key (not on just part of
  any candidate key)

The only candidate key is {isbn, copy}. So the question becomes three questions.

1. Is this relation in 1NF?
2. Are any of the non-prime attributes
   {authorID, authorName, title,
   classiﬁcation, userID} dependent only
   on {isbn}?
3. Are any of the non-prime attributes
   {authorID, authorName, title,
   classiﬁcation, userID} dependent only
   on {copy}?

What do *you* think?

---

**Later . . .**

> Then I'm creating separate table with
>   attributes: isbn, autorID, autorName,
>   title, Classification and another
>   table with attributes: isbn, copy,
>   userID.

Yes. In "relational speak", you replaced the original relation R with these two projections.

- R<sub>1</sub> = {**isbn, copy**,
  userid}
- R<sub>2</sub> = {**isbn**, authorid,
  authorname, title, classification}

If you've done that correctly, you should be able to create R again by joining R<sub>1</sub> and R<sub>2</sub> on {isbn}.

Now both R<sub>1</sub> and R<sub>2</sub> are in 2NF. (I think that was the point of the homework question.) You might want to consider whether R<sub>1</sub> and R<sub>2</sub> are in

- 3NF
- BCNF
- 4NF
- 5NF

---

**Still later . . .**

Speaking informally, a relation is in 3NF iff

- it's in 2NF, and
- there are no transitive dependencies.

When I say "it's in 2NF", I mean the relation in question is in 2NF *and* it's not *already* in 3NF, BCNF, 4NF, or 5NF.

What normal form are R<sub>1</sub> and R<sub>2</sub> in? You'll want to explain your reasoning, otherwise your lecturer is liable to make you look foolish. And we don't want that.

- R<sub>1</sub> = {**isbn, copy**,
  userid}
- R<sub>2</sub> = {**isbn**, authorid,
  authorname, title, classification}

**And still later . . .**

R<sub>1</sub> is in 5NF. R<sub>2</sub> is in 2NF.

R<sub>2</sub> isn't in 3NF, because there's a transitive dependency between "isbn" and "authorname".

- isbn->authorid, and
- authorid->authorname

Remove this transitive dependency by replacing R<sub>2</sub> with these two projections (R<sub>3</sub> and R<sub>4</sub>).

- R<sub>1</sub> = {**isbn, copy**, userid} (5NF)
- R<sub>3</sub> = {**isbn**, authorid, title, classification}
- R<sub>4</sub> = {**authorid**, authorname}

I don't think there's a functional dependency between title and classification.

Comment: @Catcall could you please provide a proper answer (some form of table) instead of asking me a question? I don't find it helpful at all. As for answering your question: Yes, Yes, Yes

Comment: @There is nothing we can do: I could provide tables, but that wouldn't be helping you with your homework. It would be doing your homework for you. Which non-prime attributes are dependent only on {isbn}? And having identified those attributes, what are you supposed to do with them?

Comment: @CatCall Attributed dependent only on isbn: authorID, authorName, title and classification. Then I'm creating separate table with attributes: isbn, autorID, autorName, title, Classification and another table with attributes: isbn, copy, userID. What do you say to that?

Comment: @There is nothing we can do: I say, "Good job." Which non-prime attributes are dependent only on {copy}?

Comment: @Catcall the other attributes which are dependent only on copy it looks like it is userID but somewhat cannot understand that.

Comment: @There is nothing we can do: My guess is that "user_id" is kind of like a library card number. If that's the case--and you're the only one that can say for sure--then it's not dependent only on "copy"; it's dependent on {isbn, copy}. (A user checks out one particular copy of one particular book.)

Comment: @Catcall, yes user_id is kind of a card number so what now?

Comment: @Catcall so I understand that this is the end of moving to 2NF, am I right?

Comment: @There is nothing we can do: You're right. I edited my answer to include your conclusions, and added another question. But now both projections are in 2NF.

Comment: @Catcall thanks a lot. Now I have another question for you. How to move from 2nd to third? Would it be this way: Table_0{isbn,authorID,title, classification}, Table_1 {isbn,title}, Table_2 {author, authorName},Table_3 {title,classification}?

Comment: @CatCall This is what I've come up with: Table_0{isbn,authorID,title,} with foreign keys authorID and title, Table_1 {isbn,title}, Table_2 {author, authorName},Table_3 {title,classification}? Looking forward to your opinion. By the way, I've never came across such nice way of dealing with people as you dealing. Thank, pure pleasure.

Comment: @There is nothing we can do: No. You're approaching the problem the wrong way. You're trying to reduce redundancy before you've identified it. (Normalization reduces redundancy.) There's no point in trying to reach 3NF if a relation is already in 5NF, and it's not unusual at all to go straight from 2NF to 5NF. What normal form is R<sub>1</sub> in? R<sub>2</sub>? Use Wikipedia if you don't have any other references.

Comment: @Catcall R1 is in 3NF and R2 in 2NF.

Comment: @There is nothing we can do: You're wrong about R<sub>1</sub>, but you're right about R<sub>2</sub>. Why is R<sub>2</sub> not in 3NF? What's wrong with it? (Don't decompose it into two or more relations, just identify the problem.) And you'll need to try again with R<sub>1</sub>. R<sub>1</sub> is in either BCNF, 4NF, or 5NF.

Comment: R2 is not in 3NF because I have transitive dependency from isbn->authorID and authorID->authorName. It looks to me like R1 is in BCNF so it could be decomposed to 4NF {isbn,userID} and {copy,userID}

Comment: You're right about the transitive dependency in R<sub>2</sub>. R<sub>1</sub> is already in 5NF. You can't decompose it further without either losing information or creating false information. (It's worth your trying to do that in a SQL dbms.) You seem to think that a relation that's in 2NF must be decomposed four times before you reach 5NF. That's a common misunderstanding.

Comment: @Catcall ok so we have R1 sorted, what about R2? Would {isbn, authorID, title} and {authorID, authorName} and {title,classificatinon} moved it to the 3NF?

Comment: @Catcall so what you're saying?

Comment: I'm saying that, as the homework problem was presented, you're finished when you get R<sub>1</sub>, R<sub>3</sub>, and R<sub>4</sub>. All three of those relations are in 5NF. (So they're all also in 4NF, and in 3NF.) As a database designer, I'd question "classification". As it's presented in the homework, there's a 1:1 relationship between "isbn" and "classification". I think a 1:n relationship is more likely--a single isbn could be classified as _historical fiction_, _psychological thriller_, and _detective_, all at the same time. But that seems to be beyond the scope of the homework.

Answer (score 1):

Have your classification & author in a separate table, like so:

*Book Table*:

**isbn** AB-1234-X

**authorID** IC45

**title** The ﬁnal curtain

**copy** 2

**classiﬁcationID** 1

**userID** xyz44

*Author Table*:

**AuthorID**

**AuthorName**

*Classfication*:

**ClassificationID**

**ClassificiationName**

Comment: Move your AuthorName to a separate table also (didn't see that on first pass :P) I've edited my answer (might need a little help with formatting)

Comment: @James according to what rules did you've created this tables? Where did you take ClassificationID, and ClassificationName from? And could you please clearly state where is the start of each table.

Comment: ClassificationId would be a surrogate key for the new Classification Table, and the ClassificationName is removed from the first table and put into this new table. The AuthorName is removed from the first table and put into a new Author Table, along with a new surrogate key. See @Catcall's answer for the rule on 2NF.

Comment: @JamesLove: Surrogate keys don't have anything to do with normalization.

Comment: @JamesLove: Inventing a new attribute called ClassificationID has nothing to do with normalization and 2NF.

Comment: For the benefit of others and myself (mostly myself, been so long since I read up on data modelling) - what is it that I'm thinking of when it comes to surrogate keys?

Comment: @JamesLove: I'm not psychic, but I suppose you're thinking about some kind of problem with your dbms. Some people use surrogate keys because they think--rightly or wrongly--that joins on natural keys are unbearably slow. But _slow_ describes behavior at the physical level; it's a quality-of-implementation issue, not a relational design issue. Often overlooked is the fact that using a natural key often avoids the join in the first place.

Comment: Ah ok, I've always had the assumption, to date, that a surrogate key removes any ambiguity that may arise when normalising data out to other tables... though thinking about it, it's the data in the keys that currently exist that you're focussing on when normalising the data - thanks for clarifying for me :)