# Convert table to 2NF - strange table to convert?

Tags: database, database-design, database-normalization, database-table

I have the following table below and am supposed to convert it to 2NF.

[image: Convert table to 2NF]

I have an answer to this where I have gone:

> SKILLS: Employee, Skill
>
> LOCATION: Employee, Current Work
>   Location

I have a feeling I'm wrong with this ^above^ though.

Also can someone explain what the differences are between 1NF, 2NF and 3NF. I know 1 comes first and you have to break it all up into smaller tables but would like a really good description to help me understand better. Thanks

Comment: NF differences:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/723998/can-someone-please-give-an-example-of-1nf-2nf-and-3nf-in-plain-english

Comment: @David thanks, could you tell me whether I'm right with the one above though?

Comment: It looks like 3NF from what is in the post.  That doesn't necessarily mean it's going to do what you want though :)

Comment: @David how would I get it so it's in 2NF then? That's the aim of the exercise

Comment: You want to go backwards, so its in 2NF but not 3NF?

Comment: @David basically, yes. I'll be marked down otherwise...

Comment: @David the table was in 1NF and I was meant to turn it into 2NF or so my teacher said...

Comment: Assuming the key to your new tables is "Employee", your new tables are in 5NF. (And 4NF, and BCNF, and 3NF, and 2NF.)

Comment: That is the answer wikipedia provides, but to get credit at my university you would need to explain how you arrived at that conclusion.

Comment: @maclunian: You might find the accepted answer and comments to this SO question helpful: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5368344/moving-to-second-form

Answer (score -2, accepted):

```
Employee Table

EmployeeID  |   Name
1       |   Jones
2       |   Bravo
3       |   Ellis
4       |   Harrison


Skills Table

SkillId     |   Skill
1       |   Typing
2       |   Shorthand
3       |   Whittling
4       |   Light Cleaning
5       |   Alchemy
6       |   Juggling

Location Table

LocationId  |   Name
1       |   114 Main Street
2       |   73 Industrial Way

EmployeeSkill Table

EmployeeId  |   LocationId  |   SkillId |   SkillName
1       |   1       |   1   |   Typing
1       |   1       |   2   |   Shorthand
1       |   1       |   3   |   Whittling
2       |   2       |   4   |   Light Cleaning
3       |   2       |   5   |   Alchemy
3       |   2       |   6   |   Juggling
4       |   2       |   4   |   Light Cleaning
```

In the EmployeeSkill table the primary key would be EmployeeId + LocationId, this gives you the skill they have at that location.  Including the SkillName column violates 3NF in this example.
This practice is actually used sometimes in database design (and called "denormalization") in order to reduce joins to increase performance reading data that is commonly used together.
Ususally this is only done in tables used for reporting.

Comment: You're introducing guaranteed-unique keys, which is good practice in general but irrelevant to the assignment, and it isn't clear that assigning a SkillId is necessary.  I'm also not fond of joining tables that embody both one-to-one and one-to-many relationships.

Comment: Yes, it was difficult to tell exactly what the end format would likely be, is a skill dependent upon a location or not?

Comment: -1. In the context of homework and education, students are expected to work with the columns in the assignment. They're not allowed to introduce new columns. One risk is that a wall of numbers obscures what's really happening. Another is that introducing new columns with id numbers seems to suggest to students  that "normalizing" means "substitute id numbers for strings".

Comment: Typically anything that has a primary key meets BCNF (3.5 NF)

Comment: -1. The answer is a bad example. Normalization has nothing to do with inventing new keys for things.

Comment: @Woot4Moo: If your university taught you that anything having a primary key meets BCNF, ask for your money back. They've served you badly.

Comment: @catcall 99.8% of tables that have primary keys meet bcnf.

Comment: @David: The OP said he needed to convert a table to 2NF. He didn't ask any questions about surrogate ID numbers.

Comment: and this meets 2NF, nothing was specified about keeping the same columns or not adding anything.

Comment: @David, The question specifies that you should *convert* [a given set of attributes and related dependencies] to 2NF. Supplying a *different* set of attributes that allegedly satisfies 2NF is not answering the question. E.g. it looks like you assumed the dependency Employee->"Current Work Location" is supposed to be satsified but then you replaced "Employee" with two other attributes and you haven't even said whether either or both of these are keys. Without specifying the keys and dependencies it's not clear that you've answered the question at all, let alone whether it might satisfy 2NF.

Answer (score 0):

I am new to learning 2NF but I have solved the answer like this. Let me know if this is correct so that I can understand my mistake and practice more.

[image]
Only two tables. Thanks